# Laravel Raw Select Returning Repeated Values

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-collection

I have the following test method in my model, it gets the length of a json column in a row:

```
public function test(){
    return $this->select(DB::raw('JSON_LENGTH((SELECT comments FROM lab_evals WHERE id='.$this->id.'))'))->get();
    }
```

In tinker it returns this:

```
= Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#7430
    all: [
      App\Models\LabEval {#7429
        JSON_LENGTH((SELECT comments FROM lab_evals WHERE id =50)): 2,
      },
      App\Models\LabEval {#7431
        JSON_LENGTH((SELECT comments FROM lab_evals WHERE id =50)): 2,
      },
    ],
  }
```

Not really a big deal since I can just call first(), but I'm wondering why there are two objects in the collection instead of one.

I would expect this:

```
= Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#7430
    all: [
      App\Models\LabEval {#7429
        JSON_LENGTH((SELECT comments FROM lab_evals WHERE id =50)): 2,
      },
    ],
  }
```

Edit: Here's the raw SQL that Laravel generates for this query for some model.

```
"select JSON_LENGTH((SELECT comments FROM lab_evals WHERE id=50)) from `lab_evals`"
```

The result I'm getting would make sense.

This is the proper raw SQL, but still not sure how I could translate this to a Laravel DB query builder.

```
(SELECT JSON_LENGTH((SELECT comments from lab_evals WHERE id=50)));
```

Edit 2:

I ended up just doing this, marking as solved:

```
DB::select('SELECT JSON_LENGTH((SELECT comments from lab_evals WHERE id='.$this->id.'))')
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish ?

Answer (score 0):

Move your where out of the select, right now it's not applied to the whole query, only your specific select. Something like this should do the trick.

```
return $this->select(DB::raw('JSON_LENGTH((SELECT comments FROM lab_evals))'))->where('id', $this->id)->get();
```

Comment: The (SELECT comments FROM lab_evals) inside JSON_Length returns multiple rows, which results in an error of course.